# ASP.NET tableless css forms

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have to create a web form in ASP.NET.

this is my HTML:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="label" AssociatedControlID="DropDownList1"></asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
</div>
<div>
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="label" AssociatedControlID="TextBox1"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
 <div>
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="" AssociatedControlID="Button1"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
</div>
</form>
```

Is this the most customizable HTML code by CSS?

Do you usually write a different markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML looks fine to me. I wouldn't personally use all those `div`s but I also don't know your exact requirements.

Some people consider a a form to be a list and will code it as:

```
<ul>
  <li>
     <label ... />
     <input ... />
  </li>
</ul>
```

I don't do it this way and it depends on how you wish to describe your data.

Untimately your main consideration is how you want to describe the data you're marking up. What is the most semantic way and how does that fit in with how you want to style the data. Usually there's a middle ground if you've considered both things well.

I would also consider grouping your form fields logically using a `<fieldset>`. This will give you something extea to hook into with your CSS also.

Answer (score 0):

We created wrapper controls that do pretty much what you described.  Each of our server controls emits a div with a specified class, a label (if label text is set) and the control itself.

We've found this to be the absolute cleanest way to get the markup we want when it goes to the client; and it results in non-table forms.

We also have several classes defined such as "row", "shortRow", etc.  that set the appropriate width of the outer div and others which control the label and control width.